# how to avoid [Missing close double quote (") character.] error in google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, double-quotes

I am receiving the error below when I want to upload a data to google big query from a csv file.
I have read many similar questions but still couldn't find a simple answer around how to fix this.
Any help is much appreciated.
Regards,

Error while reading data, error message: Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 1451. Error: Missing close double quote (") character.

Comment: Could you please add data from row 1451? Is there really an entry without closing double quote character? Or do you think that the problem is in BigQuery itself?

Comment: I checked all the entries and there's no double quote character.

Comment: Is there an entry that contains an additional double quote inside the column value? Like: "first column"|"second " column"|"third column"? It might cause a problem too. Will the answer help you, if it helps you to avoid the error, but the "error" entry will be missing in the table?

Answer (score 12):

I think I found a solution. When I try to upload the data to google bigquery directly it doesn't show those options in the advanced section, however when I first upload the file into google storage area and then import the data into google query from cloud, I can see different options in the advanced section. I simply enabled the "Allow quoted newlines" in advanced section and it made the trick.

Answer (score 11):

Encountered the same issue and figure out on my own as well. It has something to do with the Advanced Options under the Write Preference change it to "Append to table" and checked the "Quoted Newlines"

[image: error]

Comment: Quoted newlines is what fixed it for me!

Answer (score -1):

I think I found the answer. While file size is definitely a reason, another is to choose the right Table type while uploading your bucket to the Bigquery.

[image: Check the image for detail]